# Rewriting urls in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following directory structure:

```
public
-dashboard
 -app
  -components
   -batch-servers
 -index.html
```

The DocumentRoot of the Apache server is pointing at public folder. So when I hit the url `http://host/dashbaord`, it works correctly by displaying the `index.html`.

Now, suppose my url is `http://host/dashboard/batch-servers` or anything for that matter after `http://host/dashboard/`, I want it to redirect to `http://host/dashboard/index.html`. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by anything? If the request is `dashboard/app` (which exists), even then you want the redirect?

Comment: At the moment, when I hit `http://host/dashboard/batch-servers`, it gives a 404 not found. However if I first go to `http://host/dashboard/index.html` and then follow the `batch-servers` link it gets routed to `http://host/dashboard/batch-servers`. The routes in this case are manager by Angular (my frontend).